# how to add params in findpaged in ember.js

Tags: ember.js

I am new to ember.I want to know about findpaged.Please consider the below code

```
  var route = this;
  var result = route.findPaged('student', {
   "page": 1,
   "per_page": 10,
   "searchParam": searchParam,
   "moduleName": "English",
   "classId":"A"
  });
  route.controller.set("students", result); 
}
```

I could not understand the above code.My understanding is findpaged is used to pagination.page,perpage,searchParam,modulename,classId are requestparam values for server side request.

1.Here is student modelname?

2.how to add the requestmapping value?

Example: url is http://localhost:8080/students/**getstudentlist**?page=1&per_page=10&classId=A&&moduleName=English

My question is how to add call this service in above findpaged code?
Thanks.

Comment: route.findPaged is *not* a standard ember functionality. Its ether your custom code or from an addon.

Answer (score 0):

Is your route using the **RouteMixin** provided by the **ember-cli-pagination** addon?